# Java. Как получить из request.getRemoteAddr() IP-Address в формате IPv4?

Tags: java

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,...
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String userIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Таким образом получаю IP-Address пользователя, приславшего запрос. Но он получается в формате IPv6. 
Как получить в IPv4 ?

Comment: А попробуй с другого компа, чтоб он не localhost'ом был. Подозреваю, что тогда будет v4.

Comment: вот, держите: https://routing-bits.com/2009/03/19/converting-ipv4-to-ipv6/

Comment: Вы не можете сконвертировать IPv6 в IPv4, если к вам пришел запрос по IPv6, он пришел с IPv6-адреса и вы ничего не можете с этим сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у каждого домена могут бьть адреса обоих версий протокола: ipv6 и ipv4. И это **клиент выбирает**, по какому ip стучаться, из тех, которые ему предоставил DNS-сервер. Так как ipv6 новее, то он будет по возможности стучаться через ipv6. Но можно заставить DNS-сервер отдавать для указанного домена только ipv4-адреса, если конечно есть возможноть вносить такие настройки в DNS-сервер)

Я полагаю, что в твоём случае, ты просто запускаешь приложение локально, аля через `localhost`. Если это так, то просто добать опцию при запуске:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

и твой сервер будет работать через ipv4-адрес.

---

Однако, это вообще не очень надежный способ узнавать ip-адрес клиента. В большинстве реальных приложениях между клиентом и `java`-сервером стоят прокси-сервера (к примеру `nginx`). Поэтому указанный метод вернёт тебе ip-адрес сервера с nginx. Чтобы избежать такой ситуации обычно на стороне `nginx`, при приходе запроса от пользователя, в этот запрос докидывают куку с ip-адресом пользователя и уже после запрос отправляются на обработку в java-сервер. Обычно имя этой куки `X-Real-IP`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Inet4Address http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format